# random coin flip program with bank

Tags: python

I'm having some trouble trying to figure out how to keep a running total for this random coin flip program.

I am able to get to do the coin flip 1000 times and get it to print with the 500 + 25 and 500 - 25 but I cant get it to keep a running total.

```
import random
tries = 0
x = 500
while tries < 1000
    tries += 1
    coin = random.randint(1,2)
    if coin == 1
        print('My bank has', (x + 25), 'and your bank has', (x - 25))
if coin == 2:
        print('My bank has', (x - 25), 'and your bank has', (x + 25))
total = tries
print(total)
```

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python running sum", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: You have multiple problems in your posted code.  I fixed the syntax error with the quotation mark.  You also have a misplaced `if`.  On top of that, you're trying to represent both "my bank" and "your bank" with a single variable, which you never update.  You need to re-think that part of the code.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  I'm just starting to learn this and it helps to get any advice i can.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a tutorial resource.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.  Best of all, each tutorial will teach you a collection of related techniques, rather than merely solving the immediate problem.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about my question being so broad.  I'm just getting familiar with the page.  Do you have any tutorials you would suggest?

Comment: Again, please read the posting guidelines.  Asking for off-site resources is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Well you need to initialise the two 'banks' to 500 before the loop, and then in each iteration check the banks are non zero and increment / decrement as appropriate.

Note: this requires python >= 3.6 (I think) but only for the f-string print statement! So just remove it if you are using an older version.

```
import random

max_tries = 1000
bank_1 = 500
bank_2 = 500

for tri in range(max_tries):
    if (bank_1 <= 0 or bank_2 <= 0):
        print(f"finished after {tri} tries")
        break

    coin = random.randint(1,2)

    if coin == 1:
        bank_1 += 25
        bank_2 -= 25
    elif coin == 2:
        bank_1 -= 25
        bank_2 += 25

    print(f"Try: {tri}")
    print(f"\tMy bank: {bank_1}")
    print(f"\tYour bank: {bank_2}")
```

To make it cleaner you could wrap each player in a class with the some fields like bank and name. You could also have methods to increment / decrement and check for non zero, it would be a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

The quick fix to make the code work would be actually changing the `x` value based on the coin result and printing the current state based on the new value. The code would look like this:

```py
import random
tries = 0
x = 500
while tries < 1000:
    tries += 1
    coin = random.randint(1, 2)
    if coin == 1:
        x += 25
    if coin == 2:
        x -= 25
    print('My bank has', (x), 'and your bank has', (1000 - x))
total = tries
print(total)
```

But there are still some changes that i would consider to further improve the code like using `for in range` instead of `while tries`, making the coin flip from 0 to 1 (for better if check) and using the ternary operator for value changes. The result would be:

```py
import random
x = 500
tries = 1000
for i in range(tries):
    coin = random.randint(0, 1)
    x += 25 if coin else -25
    print('My bank has', (x), 'and your bank has', (1000 - x))
print(tries)
```

Comment: awesome this makes a lot of sense.  How can I make the program stop running if either side happens to hit zero?